# Loop through folders inside the zip file using unix shell script

Tags: unix

My zip file has my folders inside. After unzipping my zip file, I want to iterate a loop for available folders inside the zip.

Inside loop condition is like below:

If my folder has index file (This is a file contains some data), then only I want to run some process (I know what this process is..). Otherwise we can ignore that folder.

Then loop will continue with other folder if there are anything

Thanks advance..

Comment: What have you tried? What is the process you want to run? I would unzip the file to a location, then inside that location, use `find` with `-execdir` to run the process (depending on what it is, of course). No loop necessary.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

(note: I assume $destdir will only contain the zipfile and its extraction!)

```
zipfile="/path/to/the/zipfile.zip"
destdir="/path/to/where/you/want/to/unzip"
indexfile="index.txt" #name of the index files
mkdir -p "$destdir" 2>/dev/null  #make "sure" it exists.. but ignore errors in case it already exists

cd "$destdir" || { echo "Can not go into destdir=$destdir" ; Exit 1 ; }
#at that point, we are inside $destdir : we can start to work:
unzip "$zipfile"
for i in ./*/ ; do  # you could change ./*/ to ./*/*/ if the zip contains a master directory too
   cd "$i" && {  #the && is important: you want to be sure you could enter that subdir!
      if [ -e ./"$indexfile" ]; then
          dosomething  # you can define the function dosomething and use it here.. 
                       # or just place commands here
      fi
      cd - #we can safely this works, as we started there...
   }
done
```

note: I iterate on `./*/` instead of `*/` as the dirname could contain a leding `-`, and therefore make `cd -something` not work (it would say it can't recognise some options!) !  this goes away with `./`, `cd ./-something` will work !

Comment: Hi ./*/ was not working.. It's giving following error: bash: ./test1/: Is a directory

Comment: for i in $(find . -type d ) try this for loop.

Comment: @user3436748: it is best to use my method ( `for i in ./*/ ; do ...` ) than a `find` or a `ls` (Please see answers 1 and 3 on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls !!)  And I am surprised : are you sure you copy/pasted EXACTLY my program? as I don't see where it would say this error message...