# Remove subdirectories inside main directory using unix command

Tags: unix

I need unix command to Remove sub directories inside main directory.

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

try this .`rm -rf <dir>/*`

Comment: not working.. It's giving rm: ./test1 is a directory
rm: ./test2 is a directory
 Error..   test1 & test2 are my folder names

Comment: Hi can you look at this link and advise.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534290/loop-through-folders-inside-the-zip-file-using-unix-shell-script